# Python: complex list comprehensions where one var depends on another (x for x in t[1] for t in tests)

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to do something like:

```
all = [ x for x in t[1] for t in tests ]
```

tests looks like:

```
[ ("foo",[a,b,c]), ("bar",[d,e,f]) ]
```

So I want to have the result

```
all = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

My code does not work, Python says:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 't' referenced before assignment
```

Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: I don't understand the need of the x for x in your case. Why don't you just use all = [t[1] for t in tests] ?

Comment: `[t[1] for t in tests]` will return a list of tuples. `[x for t in tests for x in t[1]]` is a flat list (concatenation of these tuples).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should work the other way around:

```
all = [x for t in tests for x in t[1]]
```

Comment: I think Python's choice of order for multiple-`for` list comprehensions was a mistake. I understand it's trying to replicate the use of nested for statements but I find the results unreadable and tend to avoid it.

Comment: @bobince +1 totally agreed, if the intent was to keep it coherent with the normal `for`, a better way would have been just to surround the block with brackets like `[for x in l: f(x)]`; but in this case keeping the usage and the definition of the loop variables closer makes more sense.

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt, don't use list comprehensions.

Try `import this` in your Python shell and read the second line:

```
Explicit is better than implicit
```

This type of compounding of list comprehensions will puzzle a lot of Python programmers so at least add a comment to explain that you are removing strings and flattening the remaining list.

Do use list comprehensions where they are clear and easy to understand, and especially, do use them when they are idiomatic, i.e. commonly used because they are the most efficient or elegant way to express something. For instance, [this Python Idioms article](http://jaynes.colorado.edu/PythonIdioms.html) gives the following example:

```
result = [3*d.Count for d in data if d.Count > 4]
```

It is clear, simple and straightforward. Nesting list comprehensions is not too bad if you pay attention to formatting, and perhaps add a comment because the braces help the reader to decompose the expression. But the solution that was accepted for this problem is too complex and confusing in my opinion. It oversteps the bounds and makes the code unreadable for too many people. It is better to unroll at least one iteration into a for loop.

Comment: I hope I understand you wrong: *don't use list comprehensions*. **Do** use list comprehensions, normal operations (like map) are very clear that way (`[f(x) for x in items]`).

Comment: I greatly prefer `map(f, items)` to `[f(x) for x in items]`.  It's like a lot of other Python idioms - e.g. `dict(zip(keys, values))` - in that once you've internalized it, using it makes code more readable by eliminating unnecessary entities.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are doing is adding together some lists, try the sum builtin, using [] as a starting value:

```
all = sum((t[1] for t in tests), [])
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a reduce to me. Unfortunately Python does not offer any syntactic sugar for reduce, so we have to use lambda:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y[1], tests, [])
```